# How can I install Kile 2.1.0 spellcheck libraries other than English?

Tags: spelling, kile, dictionaries, french

I need a french dictionary. At least, it would be nice to have any information on the location where kile stores its spell-checking dictionaries.

Comment: AFAIK Kile uses an external spell checker (ispell or aspell I think). You need to install the language support for this spell checker first. Which Linux are you using? Are you using Kile under KDE as normal or in another way (e.g. using Gnome)?

Answer (score 17):

### Languages including:

*Amharic, Arabic, Asturian, Azerbaijani, Belarusianm Bulgarian, Bengali, Breton, Catalan, Czech, Kashubian, Welsh, Danish, German, Greek, English, Spanish, Estonian, Persian, Faroese, French, Frisian, Irish, Scottish, Galician, Ancient Greek, Gujarati, Manx Gaelic, Hebrew, Hindi, Hiligaynon, Croatian, Upper Sorbia, Hungarian, Huastec, Armenian, Interlingua, Indonesian, Icelandic, Italian, Kannada, Kurdi, Kirghiz, Latin, Lithuanian, Latvian, Malagasy, Maori, Macedonian, Malayalam, Mongolian, Marathi, Malay, Maltese, Norwegian, Low Saxonm, Dutch, Chichewa, Oriya, Punjabi, Polish, Portuguese, Quechua    Runasimi, Romanian, Russian, Kinyarwanda, Sardinian, Slovak, Slovenian, Serbian, Swedish, Swahili, Tamil, Telugu, Tetum, Turkmen, Tagalog, Setswana, Turkish, Ukrainian, Uzbek, Vietnamese, Walloon, Yiddish and Zulu*

I recently ran out to this problem, and this is how i got non-english language spell check working on Ubuntu 13.10, with Kile 2.1.3

1) Run `sudo apt-get install aspell`

2) Search the right language id from [Available Aspell Dictionaries - gnu.org](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html).

3) Run `sudo apt-get install aspell-ID`, where 'ID' should be replaced with the right language id (see link above)

4) From `Configure Kile -> Editing -> Spellcheck -> Default language` - drop-down menu select the language you just installed.

5) Check the `Automatic spell checking enabled by default`  tickbox.

6) Click `OK` to save the settings. I had to press `Alt + F7` and move the screen up with arrow keys to see the button.

7) Restart Kile.

### Finnish

I tried `aspell` and `myspell` spell checkers for Finnish, and they did not have very large volabularies. The best finnish spell checker is `Voikko`. To install it, follow these steps:

1) Remove any aspell or myspell libraries with

`sudo apt-get remove --purge myspell-fi aspell-fi ifinnish ifinnish-large ifinnish-small`

2) Install voikko with

`sudo aptitude install openoffice.org-voikko libenchant-voikko tmispell-voikko mozvoikko`

3) Follow steps 4 to 7 from the generic instructions (above)

---

**!** *Please feel free to add the best dictionaries for your language above* **!**

Comment: This is a great instruction. It works for me. We can change the dictionary file    when editing the document.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need dictionary files (for example for Spanish you need the following files: `es_ANY.dic`, `es_ANY.aff` and `hyph_es_ANY.dic`).
The dictionaries for most languages can be found at [LibreOffice Extensions page](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any&sort_on=positive_ratings&path=%2FLibreOffice-Extensions-and-Templates%2Fextension-center&portal_type=PSCProject&SearchableText=).

Second, copy files `es_ANY.dic` and `es_ANY.aff` in the directory `/usr/share/hunspell` and file `hyph_es_ANY.dic` in the directory `/usr/share/hyphen`.

Third, in the directory `/usr/share/myspell/dicts` create symbolic links to all three files. If you are in the `/usr/share/myspell/dicts` directory, the symbolic links can be made with:

```
sudo ln -s ../../hunspell/es_ANY.dic .
sudo ln -s ../../hunspell/es_ANY.aff .
sudo ln -s ../../hyphen/hyph_es_ANY.dic .
```

Finally, restart Kile and select your newly added language from `Tools->Select Dictionary...`

Answer (score 3):

For Debian-based Linux systems (including Ubuntu & Co) this should work:

1. `sudo apt-get install kcontrol`
2. `sudo apt-get install french`
3. `kcontrol`

After doing this, you have to activate the language and restart kile and the language should then be changed.

Comment: I've got Fedora. Will this work if I find kcontrol rpm?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but I do not know if this work with fedora. Maybe you can find better help on     http://superuser.com/