# Add NON-English spell-checker and/or dictionary to Kile?

Tags: kile, document-configuration

I'm running Kile 2.1.0 on Debian 7.3 *Wheezy*, KDE desktop, 32-bit processor. I'm trying to add Italian dictionary and spell-checker to Kile's configuration. I've followed the instructions of user **np8** in [this tex.SX discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26532/how-can-i-install-kile-2-1-0-spellcheck-libraries-other-than-english/144986#144986) but it didn't work. I downloaded the *.oxt file from OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice extension's web-site, changed the ending into *.zip, unzipped it to obtain the *.dic and *.aff files. Then I transferred those into the folder `~/.config/enchant/` where only `en_US.dic` and `en_US.exc` were present (they were practically 0 Byte files, empty, since I had turned Kile's spell checker off till that point). Still not working, Kile doesn't see those files, only English and Hebrew are available:
[image]

Anyone know what I can try next?

Also, I think I have a slightly bugged version of Kile since for no rhyme or reason it keeps adding a single quote mark `'` every time I happen to type `I'm` or `it's`, see [this other discussion.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158931/how-to-stop-kile-the-editor-from-automatically-adding-quote-mark?noredirect=1#comment362772_158931)

Comment: I have a non-English spell check enabled for Kile. I installed using my package manager. I'm not using Debian but the packages I have installed are a dictionary for LibreOffice and an aspell dictionary. There are likely more options for Italian. I'm not certain which Kile is using though I suspect it is aspell (via enchant). For the quotes, go to Configure Kile... and then choose Editor > Extensions. Open the config dialogue for AutoBrace and make sure that 'Automatically add closing quotation marks' is not checked.

Comment: Mmm...my Internet connection is down these days (I'm writing from another computer now). So I have to install Italian language package from `apt-get install ???` what should I write in the place of question marks?

Comment: Try searching for `aspell` and/or `italian`, I guess. It is hard for me to say since I don't use Debian. For my distro, the packages are called `aspell-xx` where `xx` is the two-letter language code e.g. `en` for English.

Comment: OFF TOPIC: After configuring the "AutoBrace" plugin in Configure Kile > Extensions, I'm getting this message box: `The autobrace plugin supersedes the Kate-internal AutoBrackets feature. The setting was automatically disabled for this document.` Now the brackets won't close automatically. This is a problem for complicated math expressions where there are many nested brackets. I'm guessing I have to un-tick some other checkbox, but where?

Comment: You only need to uncheck the option to add closing quotation marks. You could leave the option to close brackets etc. checked. (I don't find this feature works terribly well but I keep it checked because it is of some use.) Is there a different option for this?

Comment: I've noticed that the bracket option only works for round and square brackets. It doesn't autocomplete chain brackets though it used to, before activating AutoBraces plugin. Also, I followed your suggestion for `aspell-it` and installed it with Apper. It works!

Comment: So what happens if you deactivate AutoBraces? After all, you don't want it to add closing quotation marks either. In my case, having both elements activated seemed to be default so I disabled closing quotation marks to stop it adding them every time I write an apostrophe.

Comment: I hear you. I added a User-defined shortcut (from the Latex menu of Kile), and costomized it with the `%M` and `%C` place-holders.